# Pad an matrix by replicating the edge values

Tags: c, matrix, padding

My program creates a matrix. It moves and centers it into a bigger one. Now I want to fill the border created with the edge values of the first matrix to make it look like this:[image: visual example]

So far I have the following code, but it seems that it is not working as it should (let's consider the matrix as an image with width,height and border):

```
/////////////////////////Up/Down Fill////////////////////////////
for(i=border;i<(width+border);i++){
    for(j=0;j<(height+2*border);j++){
        if(j<border){
            fmatr[i][j]=fmatr[i][border];
        }
        else if(j>(height+border)){
            fmatr[i][j]=fmatr[i][(height+border)];
        }
    }
}

/////////////////////////Left/Right//////////////////////////////
for(i=0;i<(width+2*border);i++){
    for(j=0;j<(height+2*border);j++){
        if(i<border){
            fmatr[i][j]=fmatr[border][j];
        }
        else if(i>(width+border)){
            fmatr[i][j]=fmatr[(width+border)][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are a victim of an *off-one error*.

Generally in C, to iterate a sequence you use the start index and the next_to_last index, in this way:

```
for (i = first; i < next_to_last; ++i)
```

And that is handy because the next_to_last index is the first plus the length:

```
for (i = first; i < first + length; ++i)
```

If you want to know if an index is out of bounds you use `<` and `>=`:

```
out_of_bounds = i < first || i >= next_to_last;
out_of_bounds = i < first || i >= first + length;
```

All this is cool because when you have two contiguous sequences you do not have to do any adjustment when you go from one to the other:

```
for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) ...;
for (; i < b; ++i) ...;
for (; i < c; ++i) ...;
```

But if you want to access the last element of a sequence you have to remember to substract one:

```
last = array[next_to_last - 1];
last = array[first + length - 1];
```

So when you say:

```
    else if(j>(height+border)){
        fmatr[i][j] = fmatr[i][(height+border)];
    }
```

You probably mean:

```
    else if(j >= height + border){
        fmatr[i][j] = fmatr[i][height + border - 1];
    }
```

And the same with the witdh run.

---

That said I would write the inner loop as two loops. IMO your intention is clearer this way:

```
for (j = 0; j < border; ++j)
    fmatr[i][j] = fmatr[i][border];
for (j = height + border; j < height + 2 * border; ++j)
    fmatr[i][j]=fmatr[i][height + border - 1];
```

And the same with the width run.